# Polynomial regression in Maple

Tags: math, regression, maple

In Maple I have two lists

```
A:=[seq(i, i=1..10)];
B:=[10, 25, 43, 63, 83, 92, 99, 101, 101, 96];
```

Is it possible to do polynomial or power regression in Maple?

I want to fit a trend line as a 3rd order polynomium where each point is (A[i], B[i]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
Statistics:-LinearFit([1,x,x^2,x^3], A, B, x);
```